# C++ Bubble Sort, how to ignore the same numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm using bubble sort to sort numbers in an array in order from lowest to highest. But there are some numbers which are the same, but I don't need them to be printed twice. So how do I check whether it was already printed and not to repeat the action?

The Bubble sort:

```
for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){

            if(m[i]>m[j]){
                temp=m[i];
                m[i]=m[j];
                m[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When are you doing the printing?  Before/during/after the sorting?

Comment: Not really, I'm preparing for the exam next year so I'm just trying to do last year's one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since number are already sorted when you are printing it, you can store the last printed number and compare against this before printing.

Something like:

```
std::cout << m[0] << std::endl;
int last_print = m[0];

for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
{
  if(m[i] != last_print)
  {
    std::cout << m[i] << std::endl;
    last_print = m[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: Damn, why I didn't think of that xD  if(m[i]!=m[i-1]) works like a charm. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This code will not work. You defined **last_print** twice. Remove **int**

Comment: @stefanbachert, that was a copy-paste error by sleep deprived soul :-). Thanks for edit Steve.

Answer (score 4):

filter duplicate out when printing (assuming m being int[])

```
 int last = 0;
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    int num = m[i];
    if (i == 0 || last != num) {
       // print num;
    }
    last = num;
 }
```

or this way if you don't like too much vars

```
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if (i == 0 || m[i - 1] != [i]) {
       // print m[i];
    }
 }
```

Alternatively you could remove duplicates on sort

```
for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
    for(int j=i+1;j<n;){

        if (m[i]==m[j]) {  // remove
           m [j] = m [n - 1];  // replace with last
           n --;               // cut last
        } else {
          if(m[i]>m[j]){
            temp=m[i];
            m[i]=m[j];
            m[j]=temp;
          }
          j ++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the number to a `std::set` as soon as you print it, and check all numbers if they are in the set before printing them.

EDIT: I missed the restriction that the numbers are sorted. In that case, a `set` is overkill and less efficient than just keeping track of the last number printed, and only printing numbers that are different from it afterwards.

Comment: A quick example would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @RnD It's best if you research the functionality of `std::set` yourself. If you get stuck, I'll be glad to help, but I'm not going to write the code for you.

Comment: @Nikko I missed the part that the numbers are sorted.